# PHP Basic Test Page Doesn't Load (Netbeans 7.4 and WAMP)

Tags: php, netbeans, wamp

i'm studying basic PHP from zero and i'm starting with the install of WAMP, the services offered by WAMP runs with no problem, also the localhost page and PHPmyAdmin. Finally my project folder was placed on the www folder. I did a pretty simple test page, here

```
<?php echo "This is a test" ?>
```

But when i load the page, this message appears:

The requested URL /PHP/test.php was not found on this server.

It will be awesome that you can give a hand with, i'm out of ideas about this. I hope you can help me in order to start my PHP studies. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please tell me the values you actually have for URL and PHP in your url.

If your project (test.php) is in a sub folder called "myProj" in "www" folder, You should be able to access it via "http://localhost/myProj/test.php"

Comment: You mean this? project URL: http://localhost/PHP/ - index file: test.php those are on the netbeans project properties and sure i tried like http://localhost/PHP/test.php

Comment: So in your "www" folder you have a folder called "CursoPHP" and inside that you have the test.php file. When you go to that location from file browser do you see the test.php?

Comment: No. i can't. I only get the message that i showed on my question.

Comment: If you cant see the test.php file in your project folder Netbeans probably saved that file somewhere else. Double check where Netbeans has created you file.

Comment: Netbeans takes a little configuring. To start with keep it simple and enter `localhost/php/test.php` into the browser address bar. Does that run your code

Comment: PS: There is a NetBeans 8.0.2 version you might like to start using the latest version of that instead of an old version

Comment: No RiggFolly, i can't. I tried running the project from netbeans and entering localhost/php/test.php. None of those worked for me. By the way, i'm using 7.4 because my pc is kinda old, that's why. Thanks for your ansewer.

Comment: First, try to find your 'test.php' file where it is on your HDD. Second, check your apache error.log

Comment: Hmmm ok, i gonna try that tomorrow and i'll tell you how was it. Thanks! :)